# transform xml to alto xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

Hello again fellow programmers.

I have a task where i need to convert the xml output of of omnipage18 to xml alto format.

as of now, i'm using c# and linq to read the xml.

but i don't know if the output is correct.

i found a php code where it converts the `abby finereader sdk xml output` but my requirement is using `omnipage 18` and here is my question:

after reading i found this [xsd file](http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/v3/alto-3-1.xsd)
and I've read that:

> `XSD (XML Schema Definition) is a World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)
>   recommendation that specifies how to formally describe the elements in
>   an Extensible Markup Language (XML) document.`

My problem is I don't really understand how to use the XSD file. So how can I convert a omnipage xml to alto xml using what is written is the XSD file? . 
And How can this XSD guide me to convert the xml file?

XSD file is used to define the possible structure and contents of an XML format. But is how to use this as a guide to create an XSLT file?
(sorry for this dumb question)

As of now this is my c# code

```
private string OmnitoAlto(string fileName)
        {
            StringBuilder alto = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fileName);

                var coordinates = from r in document.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "wd")
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      HPOS = r.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ch").Select(n => n.Attribute("l").Value).ToArray(),
                                      VPOS = r.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ch").Select(n => n.Attribute("r").Value).ToArray(),
                                      chs = r.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ch").Select(n => n.Value).ToArray(),

                                  };

                foreach (var item in coordinates)
                {
                    alto.Append("<String HPOS=\"" + item.HPOS.First() + "\" VPOS=\"" + item.VPOS.First() + "\" Width=\"" + (Double.Parse(item.VPOS.Last()) - Double.Parse(item.HPOS.First())) + "\" CONTENT=\"" + String.Join("", item.chs) + "\"/>" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return alto.ToString();
        }
```

and here is the link of the sample [xml im converting](http://pastebin.com/LmDHRzC5)

Comment: An xsd schema file is a tool for allowing automatic checking that an xml meets the schema requirement.  You already have an xml file as an input that should of been generated correctly so you don't need to use the schema.  There are tools that will create classes automatically from the schema that you can use to de-serialize the xml.  But you can also manually parse an xml like you are doing.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a simple task of mapping one xml format to a 2nd xml format.  I answered you previous posting of how to read 1st format and now looked at the schema format of 2nd xml.  It looks like you may need to do some math to convert formats.  Good luck.

Comment: I am gonna say basically the same as jdweng. First of all, I assume you are already familiar with omnipage XML format strucure, and you know what the data contained means, is that true? I don't know anything about ALTO or omnipage formats, but I have XSD and XSLT knowledge.
You can always learn about XML Schema 1.0 using the official spec [part 1 structures](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) and [part 2 datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) or using another resource as the w3Schools tutorial (not complete, but usually an easier place to start).

Comment: XSD is quite simple, it just defines what elements can appear, how many times they appear, in what order they appear and restrincts what 'text' content the elements can have. In addition, it exists a new XSD 1.1 version but note that this is using XSD 1.0.
**BUT** please, note that you can start by seeing the structure of real ALTO documents, and learn about the structure [using ALTO resources](https://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/techcenter/layout.html). You can use [this page](https://devutilsonline.com/xsd-xml/generate-xml-from-xsd) to generate an XML document with example data given an XSD.

Comment: What I am saying is that I think is better to take a look at ALTO XML instance documents structure, and then go to the XSD part, and after that it will be easier to decide if this can be done (not always you can express the same in two different formats), if you can/want to do this using XSLT or manually process the XML nodes you need in c#, etc.

Comment: @jdweng and sergioFc, thank you. im looking at example alto file, but none of them are created using omnipage 18, they all use abby(i dont know why). as of now i'm going to continue to convert the omnipage xml file using c# code to alto xml, and use this http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html to check if my xml is correct